# SQL Aggregate function: Sum of some rows in another row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following scenario with sql server 2008

```
           **** Original Result ****
================================================
Year   month  Category               Count_days
================================================
2001    09     Leave                   03
2001    09     Worked Below 8hrs       18
2001    09     Worked Above 8hrs       05
2001    09     Present                  0  <----- current value
2001    10     Leave                   01
2001    10     Worked Below 8hrs       10
2001    10     Worked Above 8hrs       09
2001    10     Present                  0   <------ current value
```

Following is the criteria

```
criteria
===========
Present Count of 'x'th Month = SUM(Worked Below 8hrs count of 'x'th month) + 
                               SUM(Worked Above 8hrs count of 'x'th month )

                                    ;where x is the month
```

I want following result with satisfying above criteria

```
           **** Expected Result ****
===============================================
Year   month  Category               Count_days
================================================
2001    09     Leave                   03
2001    09     Worked Below 8hrs       18
2001    09     Worked Above 8hrs       05
2001    09     Present                 23  <-----(expecting  sum 18+05 =23)
2001    10     Leave                   01
2001    10     Worked Below 8hrs       10
2001    10     Worked Above 8hrs       09
2001    10     Present                 19  <-----(expecting sum 10+09 = 19)
```

Problem is the original result is generated by very complex query hence cant call same set again i.e. 
    Cannot use this  (This will hamper the performance of my application.)
    =================

```
select * from original (some join) select * from original
```

may be need to use the single query or It can be subquery, use of aggregate function etc.

Expecting any aggregation trick to generate my expected result????

Please help me out guys....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use sum as analytic function

```
SELECT 
year, month, cat, count_days as count_days_orig,
case cat 
  when 'Present' 
  then 
     sum (
           case 
             when cat in ('Worked Below 8hrs', 'Worked Above 8hrs') 
             then count_days 
             else 0 
           end
          ) 
     over (partition by year, month) 
  else count_days 
end                                    as count_days_calc
FROM 
(
SELECT 2001    as year, 09 as month ,   'Leave            ' as cat ,      03 as count_days FROM dual
UNION all                                                           
SELECT 2001    as year, 09 as month ,   'Worked Below 8hrs' as cat ,      18 as count_days FROM dual
UNION all                                                           
SELECT 2001    as year, 09 as month ,   'Worked Above 8hrs' as cat ,      05 as count_days FROM dual
UNION all                                                           
SELECT 2001    as year, 09 as month ,   'Present'           as cat ,      0 as count_days FROM dual 
UNION all                                                           
SELECT 2001    as year, 10 as month ,   'Leave            ' as cat ,      01 as count_days FROM dual
UNION all                                                           
SELECT 2001    as year, 10 as month ,   'Worked Below 8hrs' as cat ,      10 as count_days FROM dual
UNION all                                                           
SELECT 2001    as year, 10 as month ,   'Worked Above 8hrs' as cat ,      09 as count_days FROM dual
UNION all                                                           
SELECT 2001    as year, 10 as month ,   'Present'            as cat ,      0 as count_days FROM dual  
)
;
```

---

```
     year     month     cat    count_days_orig  count_days_calc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2001    9   Leave               3           3
    2001    9   Worked Below 8hrs   18          18
    2001    9   Worked Above 8hrs   5           5
    2001    9   Present             0           23
    2001    10  Leave               1           1
    2001    10  Worked Below 8hrs   10          10
    2001    10  Worked Above 8hrs   9           9
    2001    10  Present             0           19
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, don't know if column names are correct and stuff.

```
SELECT Year, month, category, 
   CASE Category
       WHEN 'Present'
          THEN (
          SELECT Sum(T2.Count_days)
          FROM table T2
          WHERE T2.year = T.year
          AND T2.month = T.month
          AND T2.Category NOT IN ('Present', 'Leave')
          )
       ELSE Count_days
   END
FROM table T
```

But this really feels like a wrong design...